# How to convert messy column object data using datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

Column name: Timestamp

Column dtype: Object

Example data: 2017-12-01T00:02:39

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

ValueError: time data Timestamp doesn't match format specified
```

I'm having problems converting the data within the Timestamp column into a datetime object which I can then manipulate / index by etc. I feel like the 'T' between the date and the time may be causing the issue. Is there a way to add an 'ignore' within datetime format so as to account for the 'T'?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are the contents of `df['Timestamp']` strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `pd.to_datetime` should work with or without `format` specified. The below has been tested on Pandas v0.19.2.

```
x = ['2017-12-01T00:02:39']

a = pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
b = pd.to_datetime(x)

# DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-01 00:02:39'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

assert (a == b).all()
```

There is likely other data in your series causing problems. You can check exactly which values are erroring by coercing errors and looking for null values:

```
s = pd.Series(x)
failing_values = s[pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

Comment: Great tip! You were spot on, there were some odd values hidden in the 2.3million rows and the failing_values solution picked them out. While the contents of the column are objects, Yuca is right that the other solution works perfectly if the searcher hasn't made the same (rookie) mistake, so will re-route. Thanks!